# A bomb can be made to explode or implode?

Tags: air, centripetal-force, explosions

A bomb can be made to implode or explode.  Can one be made to explode while creating a vortex at the same time?

Comment: Some nuclear bombs use implosion. Any bomb will produce vortices (this is no news, stirring coffee will produce vortices too).

Comment: Are you talking about bombs or compressors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-pinch with field curl.  Stuff swirls out, stuff swirls in, conserving linear and angular momentum.  Add helicity to the collapsing field lines,

[image: Z-pinch]

Helical plane-wave detonator; spaced helical detcord/primacord windings.  Vortex tube fed pressurized 2:1 by volume mixed hydrogen-oxygen, then ignite one end.

[image]

Spin up parallel to its long axis an internally and externally coarse-threaded thick-walled hollow cylinder of TNT, detonate from one end. Angular momentum is conserved.  Big badda boom with pulse shaping, etc.

[image: vortex ring]